# OpenCV2.4.9 - OpenCL - oclMat

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, ocl

I am currently trying to make a program in c++ using OpenCV library.
In order to accelerate my code I am trying to use OpenCV builtin ocl.
In my code I'm trying to use oclMat and I need to take a specific cell's value.
Ive tried addressing a specific cell like that:

```
oclMat ocl_image(image); //initializing the oclMat with image
ocl_image.row(i).col(j) //address the specific (i,j) cell in col_image
```

My problem now is that I couldn't find a way of convert the value I have (oclMat Header) to 'float'.
What I did for now is

```
ocl_image.row(i).col(j).download(temp) //temp is of type cv::Mat
```

And the code takes too much time to run, Is there an other way of addressing a specific cell without the need to convert between cv::ocl::oclMat and cv::Mat types?

Thank you.

Comment: Note sure if solution, but if you are creating the "temp" matrix every time then that will be slow, create it once and just write the data to it.

Comment: why not use opencv 3.0 where you could use `UMat` which is hardware  acceelerated by default ?